# Visual Studio 2010 SQL Developement Server stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I was making minor modifications to a view in my ASP.NET MVC 3 C# application when all of a sudden the application would no longer run. The error message is as follows:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Upon close inspection of the server explorer I noticed that all database connections are no longer working. I cannot expand any of the connections to view the tables and data I previously generated within. When I attempt to, there is a pop-up window that is generated that repeats the exact same error as above.

It is important to note that I was not making any modifications to any portion of the application that pertains to a database.  I was rearranging some of the visual components of a view in my application when all of this occurred. I had just recently restarted my computer and had made no other modifications since that time.

At first I thought that somehow SQL Express had overwritten my development environments version of SQL Server and began to reinstall [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express). The installation fails every time now. There is no specific error. Windows generates an error message saying that the setup application "stopped working" and hangs until closed.

I have tried several different versions of the SQL Server Express installation package, and they all result in the same error happening at different points in the installation process. To be clear, I'm not even sure SQL Server Express is the problem.  I don't know why it would be since I'm using the SQL Server edition that is built into [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the SQL service running? Check under the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express#Capabilities).

I assume you've already tried to repair install, to uninstall and to restart your computer, pray then try again?

Comment: Yes I have tried all that.  The first suggestion worked.  You saved my life!  I r noobile!

Answer (score 2):

Is the SQL service running? Check under [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express#Capabilities).

Yes, another life saved.

`Run-sqlservermanager11.msc`, right click and start.

Answer (score 1):

Are you databases remotely deployed? Because it is possible that the network is down.

Secondly, check in the we.config file if you have specified the correct credentials. Try to log in through [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio).

One more thing: Stop the SQL Server service, and start it again. Or you can reboot the system.

Comment: My databases are not remotely deployed.

There is nothing wrong with the web.config the credentials have not changed nor should they.  THey are exactly as they should be.

I have rebooted the system.  In addition to the reboot that happened only minutes prior to the error presenting.